# How to fix collect2.exe error: ld returned 1 exit status in VSCODE , for C

Tags: c, sockets, udp, serversocket

Error using VSCODE and MinGW and Coderunner extension on VSCODE

Getting error : collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status

The code is

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <winsock2.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <winsock.h>

#pragma comment(lib, "ws2_32.lib")

int main() {
    WSADATA wsa;
    SOCKET sockfd;
    struct sockaddr_in server_addr, client_addr;
    int portno;
    int client_len = sizeof(client_addr); // Change socklen_t to int
    char buffer[1024];

    // Initialize Winsock
    if (WSAStartup(MAKEWORD(2, 2), &wsa) != 0) {
        printf("Failed to initialize Winsock\n");
        return 1;
    }

    // Server configuration
    portno = 12346;
    memset(&server_addr, 0, sizeof(server_addr));
    server_addr.sin_family = AF_INET;
    server_addr.sin_addr.s_addr = INADDR_ANY;
    server_addr.sin_port = htons(portno);

    // Create socket
    if ((sockfd = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM, 0)) == INVALID_SOCKET) {
        printf("Error opening socket\n");
        return 1;
    }

    // Bind socket
    if (bind(sockfd, (struct sockaddr*)&server_addr, sizeof(server_addr)) == SOCKET_ERROR) {
        printf("Error binding socket\n");
        closesocket(sockfd);
        WSACleanup();
        return 1;
    }

    while (1) {
        ssize_t bytes_received = recvfrom(sockfd, buffer, sizeof(buffer), 0, (struct sockaddr*)&client_addr, &client_len);

        if (bytes_received < 0) {
            printf("Error receiving data\n");
            break;
        }

        // Display received data
        buffer[bytes_received] = '\0';  // Null-terminate the received data
        time_t current_time = time(NULL);
        printf("%ld %s %s\n", current_time, ctime(&current_time), buffer);
    }

    closesocket(sockfd);
    WSACleanup();

    return 0;
}
```

Its purpose :

Overall Functionality

This code creates a simple UDP server in C that listens for incoming messages on port 12346. When a message arrives, it timestamps the message and prints it to the console.

Header Files and Setup

```
#include <stdio.h> : Includes standard input/output functions like printf and scanf.
#include <stdlib.h> : Provides general utilities like memory allocation.
#include <string.h>: Includes string manipulation functions (e.g., memset).
#include <winsock2.h> and #include <winsock.h>: Brings in libraries for network programming on Windows.
#pragma comment(lib, "ws2_32.lib"): Instructs the linker to automatically link the Winsock library.
Main Function (main)
```

Winsock Initialization:

WSADATA wsa: A structure to hold Winsock initialization data.
WSAStartup(): Initializes the Winsock library.
Socket Creation:

SOCKET sockfd: A file descriptor representing the socket.
socket(): Creates a UDP socket (SOCK_DGRAM)
Server Address Setup:

struct sockaddr_in server_addr, client_addr: Structures for holding internet addresses.
portno = 12346: The port number where the server will listen.
memset(): Clears the memory of the server address structure.
server_addr.sin_family = AF_INET: Specifies IPv4.
server_addr.sin_addr.s_addr = INADDR_ANY: Listen on all available interfaces.
server_addr.sin_port = htons(portno): Port number in network byte order.
Binding the Socket:

bind(): Assigns the prepared address to the socket.
Receiving Data Loop:

while (1): Runs indefinitely.
recvfrom(): Receives a datagram (message) from the socket and stores sender address.
buffer[bytes_received] = '\0': Ensures the received data is null-terminated for use as a string.
time() and ctime(): Get the current time and format it.
printf(): Prints the timestamp, formatted time, and received message.
Cleanup:

closesocket(): Closes the socket.
WSACleanup(): Releases Winsock resources.

```
[Running] cd "c:\Users\gseid\Documents\.vscode\" && gcc openbcisocket.c -o openbcisocket && "c:\Users\gseid\Documents\.vscode\"openbcisocket
C:\Users\gseid\AppData\Local\Temp\cc533lEm.o:openbcisocket.c:(.text+0x35): undefined reference to `WSAStartup@8'
C:\Users\gseid\AppData\Local\Temp\cc533lEm.o:openbcisocket.c:(.text+0x98): undefined reference to `htons@4'
C:\Users\gseid\AppData\Local\Temp\cc533lEm.o:openbcisocket.c:(.text+0xbe): undefined reference to `socket@12'
C:\Users\gseid\AppData\Local\Temp\cc533lEm.o:openbcisocket.c:(.text+0xfd): undefined reference to `bind@12'
C:\Users\gseid\AppData\Local\Temp\cc533lEm.o:openbcisocket.c:(.text+0x11c): undefined reference to `closesocket@4'
C:\Users\gseid\AppData\Local\Temp\cc533lEm.o:openbcisocket.c:(.text+0x124): undefined reference to `WSACleanup@0'
C:\Users\gseid\AppData\Local\Temp\cc533lEm.o:openbcisocket.c:(.text+0x167): undefined reference to `recvfrom@24'
C:\Users\gseid\AppData\Local\Temp\cc533lEm.o:openbcisocket.c:(.text+0x18a): undefined reference to `closesocket@4'
C:\Users\gseid\AppData\Local\Temp\cc533lEm.o:openbcisocket.c:(.text+0x192): undefined reference to `WSACleanup@0'
collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

Comment: `#pragma comment(lib, "ws2_32.lib"): Instructs the linker to automatically link the Winsock library.` I am not sure about that, but I would assume this is only working with MS compiler. For GCC you probably need to provide correct libraries to your command line yourself.

Comment: Besides that, your title is not very useful. The message you copied is only the summary and means "something went wrong somewhere". That doesn't helpt at all. It will also not help when you put in into Google to search for a solution. Instead you need to look at the detailed messages: `undefined reference to 'WSAStartup@8'` You will find much more useful hits when you put this into Google or into the searchbox here at StackOverflow.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [C - Undefined Reference to WSAStartup@8'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34384803/c-undefined-reference-to-wsastartup8)

Comment: Usually look at the first error you get, not the last one